# Why is my Program Returning the Amount of Times Rather Than the Number Itself?

Tags: python

I am trying to return the number in the list that occurs an odd number of times. Right now, it is returning the amount of times the number is present in the list. For instance, in this code, what is being returned is `[3, 3, 3]` I want it to return `4`

```
def num_occurrence_lc(arr, num):
    lc = [1 for x in arr if x == num]
    return sum(lc)

def getOddOccurrence_lc(arr):
    """returns the number stated an odd number of times in the
    sequence"""
    num_occ_list = [num_occurrence_lc(arr, x) for x in arr]
    odd_occ_list = [z for z in [z for z in num_occ_list if z%2!=0]]
    return odd_occ_list
print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have made a mistake in `num_occurrence_lc(arr, num)`. You are storing the counts rather than the number itself. Try instead the following:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def count_num(arr, num):
    return arr.count(num)

def getOddOccurrence_lc(arr):
    count_tup = namedtuple('num_count', ['num', 'count'])
    arr_counts = [count_tup(str(num), count_num(arr, num)) for num in list(set(arr))]
    odd_arr_counts = [int(tup.num) for tup in arr_counts if tup.count%2 != 0]
    return odd_arr_counts
```

If you run `print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,4]))` you will get the output:

```
>>> print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,4]))
[4]
```

The reason why I made the output a list instead of a single number is to generalize the `arr` input, to take into account the possibility that there may be more than one number with an odd number of occurrences. So for example, with `print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,1,4]))` you will get:

```
>>> print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,1,4]))
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_occurrence_lc` just returns the number of occurrences, and you never look at `arr` again, so it should be pretty clear that you're not going to be able to recover the original list elements.  If this isn't clear, I'd suggest printing `num_occ_list`.

One option is to have num_occ_list store a pair: each element in the list along with its count.  Something like this:

```
num_occ_list = [(x,num_occurrence_lc(arr, x)) for x in arr]
```

You can then pull out just the original list element once you've checked its count:

```
odd_occ_list = [x for (x,z) in num_occ_list if z%2!=0]
```

If you run this, you'll see the result is `[4,4,4]`.  This is because you called num_occurrence_lc every time an element appeared.  Since you really just want to call it once for each unique element, you can transform the array into a set first:

```
num_occ_list = [(x,num_occurrence_lc(arr, x)) for x in set(arr)]
```

Again, I'd suggest printing out num_occ_list to understand what this is producing.  With these two lines, you should get `[4]`, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Little modification and it is working

```
def num_occurrence_lc(arr, num):
    lc = [1 for x in arr if x == num]
    return sum(lc)
def getOddOccurrence_lc(arr):
    odd_occ_list = [x for x in list(set(arr)) if num_occurrence_lc(arr, x)%2!=0]
    return odd_occ_list
print(getOddOccurrence_lc([1,2,4,2,4,1,4]))
```

returning [4]

Explanation:

`x for x in list(set(arr))` Put the value of x from the set of arr only if function `num_occurrence_lc(arr, x)` returns an odd number